# How to sort a statically initiallized 2-D array with std::sort?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, std

I initialized a 2-D array (`n rows * 2 cols`), and I want to sort it by `std::sort` like this:

```
// before std::sort
4 6
3 3
2 3

// after std::sort
2 3
3 3
4 6
```

The `cmp` function is like this:

```cpp
static bool cmp(int m1[2], int m2[2]) 
{
    if (m1[1] != m2[1])
        return m1[1] < m2[1];
    return m1[0] < m2[0];
}
```

All codes are here:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int ministers[1010][2];
int n, a, b;

static bool cmp(int m1[2], int m2[2]) 
{
    if (m1[1] != m2[1])
        return m1[1] < m2[1];
    return m1[0] < m2[0];
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d%d%d", &n, &a, &b);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d %d", &ministers[i][0], &ministers[i][1]);
    std::sort(ministers, ministers+n, cmp);
    return 0;
}
```

But the CLione editor gives me a static error:
[static error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQX4j.png)

And when I tried to compile this code, compiling error occurred:

```
====================[ Build | Vijos | Debug ]===================================
"F:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.2.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build E:\MyFilesCosec\CLionProjects\Vijos\cmake-build-debug --target Vijos -j 16
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Vijos.dir/main.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/Vijos.dir/main.cpp.obj 
"F:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\c++.exe"   -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Vijos.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\Vijos.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/Vijos.dir/main.cpp.obj -c E:/MyFilesCosec/CLionProjects/Vijos/main.cpp
In file included from F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/algorithm:62,
                 from E:/MyFilesCosec/CLionProjects/Vijos/main.cpp:2:
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]':
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1885:25:   required from 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]'
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1971:31:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]'
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = int (*)[2]; _Compare = bool (*)(const int*, const int*)]'
E:/MyFilesCosec/CLionProjects/Vijos/main.cpp:19:42:   required from here
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1850:3: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
   __val = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__i);
   ^~~~~
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1852:17: error: invalid array assignment
        *__first = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__val);
                 ^
In file included from F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:61,
                 from F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/algorithm:62,
                 from E:/MyFilesCosec/CLionProjects/Vijos/main.cpp:2:
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_heap.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__make_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]':
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1672:23:   required from 'void std::__heap_select(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]'
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1933:25:   required from 'void std::__partial_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]'
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1948:27:   required from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Size = long long int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]'
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:25:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]'
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = int (*)[2]; _Compare = bool (*)(const int*, const int*)]'
E:/MyFilesCosec/CLionProjects/Vijos/main.cpp:19:42:   required from here
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_heap.h:341:15: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
    _ValueType __value = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__first + __parent));
               ^~~~~~~
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_heap.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__pop_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]':
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1675:19:   required from 'void std::__heap_select(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]'
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1933:25:   required from 'void std::__partial_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]'
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1948:27:   required from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Size = long long int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]'
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:25:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(const int*, const int*)>]'
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = int (*)[2]; _Compare = bool (*)(const int*, const int*)]'
E:/MyFilesCosec/CLionProjects/Vijos/main.cpp:19:42:   required from here
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_heap.h:251:18: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
       _ValueType __value = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__result);
                  ^~~~~~~
F:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_heap.h:252:17: error: invalid array assignment
       *__result = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__first);
                 ^
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Your are peeking in the array out of bounds.

Comment: Fyi, qsort is a better fit for this (which is rare) if you're stuck with a native array of native arrays of `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I initialized a 2-D array (`n rows * 2 cols`), and I want to sort it by `std::sort` [...]

If the col count is always 2, then you should have used a

- [`std::pair<int, int> ministers[1010];`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) or
- [`std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 1010> ministers;`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)  or
- [`std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> ministers(1010)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

as a suitable data structure here.
This will help to compare the elements by simply the comparison [operator of `std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp).

Example using the array of `std::pair<int, int>` you might do

```
std::pair<int, int> ministers[1010]; // array of  pair of ints
int n;  std::cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    std::cin >> ministers[i].first >> ministers[i].second;
// compare function is a lambda
std::sort(ministers, ministers + n
       , [](const auto& m1, const auto& m2) { return m1 < m2; });
   // use of std::pair<int, int>::operator<  --> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8jcsWdCyxq4EgDZq)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to know why my codes cannot by compiled and how to use std::sort to sort it if the type of ministers must be like int[][]?

Comment: @XiaotianHong native arrays aren't assignable. E.g., `int a[2], b[2] = {0}; a = b;` isn't legal in C++ (or C for that matter). Such operations are required for `std::sort`. Look at each of the actual errors; they're all attempts at assignment.